# Compare two rows in the same table for equality in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have the following table in my database:

Table name: INSURANCE TABLE

```
ID | Policy 
1  | 34564  
2  | 67548  
3  | 34564  
4  | 98271  
5  | 90198  
6  | 98271
```

I am looking for a sql query that will compare the Policy column values in all 5 rows and return those rows which have a value equal to atleast one other row.

For the table above I should get the following result set:

1  | 34564

3  | 34564
 4  | 98271
 6  | 98271

I would appreciate responses on how to write this query.

Comment: is it mysql or sql-server? they are different. sql-server is Microsoft Sql Server

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you, you want to group by Policy, discarding unique values:

```
select * from your_table where Policy in (
    select Policy from your_table group by Policy having count(*) > 1
);
```